# Actionscript : Add buttonmode in loaded image

Tags: actionscript-3, load, displayobject

I tried to add a button Mode to my loaded image.
This error was shown :

```
Error #1056: Cannot create property buttonMode on flash.display.Loader.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Loader extends DisplayObjectContainer, but the buttonMode (and useHandCursor) property belongs to the Sprite class and subclasses.

So - the easiest solution is simply to make a new Sprite() and then addChild(yourLoader) to the sprite. And add the Sprite where you want the loader to be. Then assign the buttonMode and any click event listeners to that sprite.

To me, it has never made sense that the Loader class can dispatch click events and yet can't be assigned the buttonMode, so your confusion is shared in that respect!

Comment: u mean like this? addChild(load123) = new Sprite()?